# Where does 'sys.exec_prefix' point to?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've heard two descriptions.One said it points to location of compiled binaries, another believed sys.exec_prefix is the equivalent of sys.prefix, but for platform-specific files, which is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [python-3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sys.html#sys.exec_prefix):

> `sys.exec_prefix`
>
> > A string giving the site-specific directory prefix where the platform-dependent Python files are installed; by default, this is also '/usr/local'. This can be set at build time with the --exec-prefix argument to the configure script. Specifically, all configuration files (e.g. the pyconfig.h header file) are installed in the directory exec_prefix/lib/pythonX.Y/config, and shared library modules are installed in exec_prefix/lib/pythonX.Y/lib-dynload, where X.Y is the version number of Python, for example 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76395479/9230769). It contains what I understood from the Python documentation about `sys.exec_prefix` and other related variables.