# How does Python find the value for sys.prefix (resp. sys.base_prefix)?

Tags: python, unix

What is says on the tin.

I have solved the mystery of how `sys.prefix` gets set when using a virtual environment (Python looks for a `pyvenv.cfg` file [[1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/#specification)]).

However, I don't understand exactly how Python finds `sys.base_prefix`.
The default is `/usr/local` (on Unix) [[2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.prefix)].
However, that doers not seem to be in effect on my Mac.

As the code below shows, symlinks are followed, and in this case the `sys.base_prefix` is simply the directory above the actual Python binary:

```
# Following symlinks to determinw where the actual hard link is
➜  tmp ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jeffhemmen  admin  38 23 Jul 12:23 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3
➜  tmp ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jeffhemmen  staff  55 20 Jul 14:26 /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3 -> ../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
➜  tmp ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jeffhemmen  staff  9 20 Jul 14:26 /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 -> python3.8
➜  tmp ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jeffhemmen  staff  17704 23 Jul 12:23 /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8
# Printing sys.base_prefix for all these links
➜  tmp /usr/local/bin/python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.base_prefix)" 
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8
➜  tmp /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.base_prefix)"  
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8
➜  tmp /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.base_prefix)"
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8
➜  tmp /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -c "import sys; print(sys.base_prefix)"
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8
```

However, in the example below (same computer, my Mac), the `sys.base_prefix` is completely different:

```
➜  tmp ls -l /usr/bin/python3 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  31488 10 Aug 21:56 /usr/bin/python3
➜  tmp /usr/bin/python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.base_prefix)" 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7
```

I have read somewhere that this depends on how Python was installed. Does this mean the `sys.base_prefix` is actually compiled into the binary? If not is there a text file (config, .py, ...) somewhere that Python reads upon startup?

**Bonus question:** when/how/why is `sys.exec_prefix` actually different from `sys.prefix` (and/or `sys.base_exec_prefix` from sys.base_prefix`)?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) explains how the values are set and how a virtual environment overrides it.

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/sysmodule.c) for the sys module, and it seems to be set at initialization from the interpreter state. I didn't follow that path further.

Comment: I think you forgot the link for the documentation.

Comment: Thanks.  Fixed.  It was there, but I must have accidentally deleted it.

Comment: Thanks! I had a look at that documentation, but all I could find was:  
`sys.base_prefix: Set during Python startup, before site.py is run, to the same value as prefix.`
And  
`sys.prefix: ... by default, this is the string '/usr/local'. This can be set at build time with the --prefix argument to the configure script.`

So once it is built, how does my Pyhon binary know the value? Is it compiled into the binary then?

Comment: Updated my answer with more info.

Comment: Thanks for that so far; didn't know where in the SC to start looking, will do some more digging now it seems less daunting! 

Answer (score 1):

A ***Python installation directory*** is a directory containing all the directories `bin/`, `include/`, `lib/`, `share/` etc. needed by any Python installation. If you are using Ubuntu, it has as default Python installation directory `/usr`. When we create a virtual environment, a Python installation directory is created having the name of the environment. Any Python interpreter, of an environment or not, needs this directory structure to work properly. Therefore, a Python environment created with `venv` (or any other tool such as `pyenv`, `poetry` or `conda`) will create directories with these exact names.

For example, if we create a Python virtual environment with the name `my_venv` we will have the Python Installation directory structure:

```bash
~/my_python_project$ python3 -m venv my_venv
~/my_python_project$ tree my_venv/ -L 1
. ## This is the "Python Installation directory" structure. Notice directories bin/, lib/ etc.
├── bin
├── etc
├── include
├── lib
├── lib64 -> lib
├── pyvenv.cfg
└── share
```

When we type `python` in our shell the operating system traverses the `PATH` environment variable looking for the first executable with the name 'python'. Once it has located one (it may be a symlink, in which case it will NOT be followed), the Python script starts execution using that interpreter. Among the first things the Python script will do automatically will be to ask the OS the location of the interpreter it is using, the one that was found in the `PATH` environment variable. With that location in hand, Python (more precisely the `site.py` module) will look for a file called `pyenv.py` one level up of the `/bin` directory where the executable (or symlink) sits. If found, the interpreter will understand it is in a virtual environment; if not found, the interpreter will understand it is not in a virtual environment.

When in a virtual environment, if the the `pyvenv.cfg` file contains a `home` key, the interpreter will use it to set `sys.base_prefix` and `sys_prefix` as:

1. `sys.base_prefix` will hold the path to the *Python installation directory* used to create this virtual environment. For this, the interpreter will look at the `home` key in the `pyvenv.cfg`. This key will hold the path to the directory where the Python executable used to create this virtual environment sits. If that executable happens to be a symlink, it IS followed until the real executable. The directory hosting the `bin/` directory where that that real executable is, will be the Python installation directory of the Python executable used to build this environment. For example:

```bash
~/my_python_projects$ cat ./my_venv/pyvenv.cfg
home = /usr/local/bin   ## this is because this Python virtual environment was created from the executable
                        ## /usr/local/bin/python3, which is a symlink to /usr/bin/python3.8. 
                        ## Thus sys.base_prefix will be /usr
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.8.10
```

```bash
~/my_python_projects$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 mar  2  2022 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.8
```

```bash
~/my_python_projects$ source ./my_venv/bin/activate  ## activate the virtual environment
(my_venv) ~/my_python_projects$ python3 -c "import sys;print(sys.base_prefix)"
/usr
```

2. `sys.prefix` will point to the directory containing the `pyvenv.cfg` file, if it exist, ie. the Python installation directory of our virtual environment in case we are using one. If not using a virtual environment, will be the same as `sys.base_prefix`.

```bash
(my_venv) ~/my_python_projects$ python3 -c 'import sys;print(sys.base_prefix);print(sys.prefix)'
/usr  ## sys.base_prefix
/home/carl/my_python_projexts/env_no_ga  ## sys.prefix
```

Notice that both these "base directories" have the directory structure of a Python installation, ie. the directories `bin`, `include`, `lib` etc. Notice also that if we are not using a virtual environment, both `sys.base_prefix` and `sys.base` will be set to the OS's Python installation directory. In my case I use Ubuntu 20.04, so these variables are `/usr` when not using a virtual environment.

Also from to the Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html), *I deduce* the other two variables `sys.prefix` and `sys.base_prefix` are set as:

1. `sys.base_exec_prefix`: If in a virtual environment, it will be the same as `sys.base_prefix`, ie. the Python installation directory of the Python interpreter used to create the virtual environment. If not in a virtual environment, it will be the OS Python installation directory.
2. `sys.exec_prefix`: If in a virtual environment, it will be the same as `sys.prefix`, ie. the Python installation directory of the virtual environment. If not in a virtual environment, it will be the OS Python installation directory.

In other words, by *default* they will always be the same as `sys.base_prefix` and `sys.prefix`, respectively.

Reading the cited Python documentation on `sys.base_prefix`, `sys.prefix`, `sys.base_exec_prefix` and `sys.exec_prefix`, I concluded that all these variables are initially set to the OS's Python installation directory. After, if module `site.py` determines we are in a virtual environment, it proceeds to change them as mentioned above.

What I have not found yet is what is the rationale behind defining all these variables with different name but having the same values.

**Bibliography**

1. [Python and the Module Search Path](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-and-the-module-search-path-e71ae7a7e65f) by Mark Jamison.
2. Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.prefix)